Block IP or User Agent using Robots.txt
My site is getting hit by bot over and over and it is using all my SQL resources on the server.
66.249.**.** Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+GoogleDocs;+apps-spreadsheets;++http://docs.google.com) - 200 0 0 796

Is there any way in the robots file to either block GoogleDocs;+apps-spreadsheets or even the IP address.
Do I just add the following to my robots file?
User-agent: GoogleDocs
Disallow: /


Robots.txt is not capable of blocking anything. It's just kindly asking clients to ignore what they see. If you want to block an IP use a firewall.

A firewall will block IP-addresses and ranges and prevent them from reaching your web server entirely. In addition you can potentially also configure web server  to apply access controls. That allows you to be more granular and grant/deny access to specific sites/pages/URL's on your server.  For Apache httpd mod_authz_hosts  can block IP-addresses  and mod_rewrite, mod_security can deny access based on even more specific request attributes like a user agent header i.e. RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "The user-agent string/regex to block" and
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
